# How do I Update column based on the latest entry in a set? PostgreSQL 9.3

Tags: sql, postgresql

[image]

I have a set of record which shows how respondent move from site to site which is shown in the D and E. Assuming we are certain rows 1 to 3 (Recordid 2,4,6)  belongs to Respondent A, I would like to add column F and update it with the value "samplicio.us". How can I achieve this?

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or, even worse, links to images.)

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data as [**formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: Sorry about that, Let me get sample data. The problem is I don't even know where to start. I got the format above from processing the data from from another format, I read and probably have to use an If statement.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a query for this easily enough:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(todomain)  over (partition by respondentid order by recordid desc) as finaldestination
from t;
```

You can incorporate this into an update as well:

```
update t
    set finaldestination = tt.new_finaldestination
from (select t.*,
             first_value(todomain)  over (partition by respondentid order by recordid desc) as new_finaldestination
      from t
     ) tt
where t.recordid = tt.recordid
```